# Proving that $\{0^{m^2}\mid m\geq 3\}^*$ is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages, number-theory

We know that $L=\{0^{m^2}\mid m\geq 3 \}$ is not a regular language. However $L^*$ is regular because we can generate $0^{120}$ to $0^{128}$ by some concatenations and then any other power of $0$ can be generated just by concatenating $0^9$. Hence we can represent $L^*$ using a FSM.

**My Question :**

1. Here I got these numbers $120$–$128$ for $m^2$ by trial and error. Is there any formal method to arrive at these numbers?
2. If we consider $m^2$ to be a function such that we get $L^*$ is regular, will it also be regular for $m^3$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the language
$$
L = \{ 0^{m^k} : m \geq m_0 \}.
$$
Since $m_0$ and $m_0+1$ are relatively prime, so are $m_0^k$ and $(m_0+1)^k$. Hence every large enough integer is a non-negative integer combination of $m_0^k$ and $(m_0+1)^k$, implying that
$$L^* \supseteq \{ 0^m : m \geq M_0 \}$$
for some $M_0$, and so $L^*$ is regular. Using the classical formula of the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#Frobenius_numbers_for_small_n) applied to $m_0^k$ and $(m_0+1)^k$, we can upper bound the optimal value of $M_0$ by
$$
M_0 \leq (m_0^k-1)((m_0+1)^k-1).
$$
For example, the case considered in your post has $k=2$ and $m_0=3$, and this gives the bound $M_0 \leq (3^2-1)(4^2-1) = 120$, which is (apparently) tight in this case.

Recently it has been shown that it is $\Sigma_2^P$ hard to determine the largest integer which cannot be represented as a non-negative combination of given positive integers ([Matsubara 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05657)), though in your particular case the set $\{ m^k : m \geq m_0 \}$ has a lot of structure, and so the problem might be feasible.

Comment: Why does the subset statement $\{ 0^m : m \ge M_0 \} \subseteq L^*$ provide enough information to state that $L^*$ is regular?

Comment: I think I've worked out a specific case on my own, but was curious if that's a proven statement somewhere.

Comment: If a unary language consists of all inputs of length $\ell$ and above, then it is accepted by the regular expression $0^\ell0^*$.

Answer (score 1):

If a language contains $(0^n | 0^m)^*$ with gcd (n, m) = 1, then every integer $k ≥ n \cdot m$ is the sum of multiples of n and m, so the language contains $(0^k)$, $k ≥ n \cdot m$.

This is the case here because gcd ($3^2$, $4^2$) = gcd (9, 16) = 1, so the language contains $0^k$, $k≥144$. And it contains a few more strings $O^k$. And that is a regular language. (In this case, the language actually contains $0^k$, $k≥88$).

If you had a different language L, using terms $m^k$, $m ≥ m_0$ with large k and $m_0$ instead of $m^2$ for $m≥3$, then finding the exact grammar that demonstrates L is regular might be quite hard to find, but the argument above shows that it exists.